# Python Graphical sample application

Tags: python

Is there any sample Python GUI Application with source code for learning purposes available. Any simple GUI application will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends on the UI library/framework you want to use:

Tkinter comes with python for example - you should find plenty examples here: [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)

Other toolkits include wxWidgets: [This](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) site could get you started.

Apart from this there is QT (already mentioned by BrainStorm) or GTK (quick googeling turned up [this](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html) tutorial).

Comment: BrainStrom was to the point and exact. But, since you elaborated a little and let me know more on the issue i am marking this as answer. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Look at this tutorial: [PyQT by example](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS47.html), although there are many others out there.

Comment: thanks mate, one line solution to the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use pygtk

http://www.pygtk.org/

http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html